# Maven: Executable JAR cant find resource

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I create an executable jar with maven using the plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>pack.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> 
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal> 
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have all of the dependencies in the `src/min/resources` folder. After i build the jar, i unpack it with archive manager and i can see all of my dependencies at the root level.

Here is how i am trying to access a resource

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
dataIn = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(
                    new File(classLoader.getResource("trainingData").getFile()));
```

This runs just fine in Eclipse. But when i try to run the executable jar file, i get

```
java -jar target/my-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -o 1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'file:/path/to/myProject/target/my-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/trainingData' cannot be found
```

why is JVM looking for `File 'file:/path/to/myProject/target/my-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/trainingData'` ?

what can i do to solve this?

Comment: You can’t read a resource from a .jar file with java.io.File, period.  And *never* use the URL.getFile() method, as it *does not* convert a URL into a file name, it just returns the path and query portions of a URL.  A resource inside a .jar file isn’t a separate file.  Read it as a URL or as an InputStream.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks .